# How to add a line to an existing txt with C#

Tags: c#, text, streamwriter

I would like to an a new line to a txt file. I've tried this with StreamWriter but it seems to clear the txt then add the line i want and nothing else. I was just wondering is there away to do where i keep the data inside the txt its adding a line too?

Thanks, Josh

Comment: You need to use  `new StreamWriter("c:\\file.txt", true);` to append to a file rather than overwriting it, see the SO question in the comment by @J3soon for further details.

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
File.AppendAllText("file.txt", "Some Text to Append");
```

If you want to use `StreamWriter` then you just need to specify `true` for the `append` argument.

```
new StreamWriter("file.txt", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var writer = new StreamWriter(fileName, true);
```